# How to get NetBeans to recognize acm graphics library (Java)

Tags: java, netbeans

How to get NetBeans to recognize that I have the ACM libraries installed on my computer?  I've copied/pasted it into several locations, but always get the same error (basically saying that the package doesn't exist).  I've read on a few sites there is a java archive ("jar") file involved, but I don't know if I have it, how to create it if I don't, or where to install/copy it if I do.

As far as details go, I have a PC running Windows 7, JRE 7, and jdk1.7.0_21.  I have a "64-bit" computer, if that means anything (I know what a bit is but have no idea whether it would affect Java or NetBeans).  The error rears its ugly head when I try "import acm.graphics.*;" and similar statements.  The full error message is: "package acm.graphics does not exist".

I'm fairly new to NetBeans and I'm thinking it's probably something simple, and it would really be great to be able to use the ACM libs, so any ideas for fixing the problem would be most appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: acm libraries are? a file with extension .jar?

Comment: Well when I downloaded them, they came as a bunch of folders, each with a bunch of class files for objects like GRect, GLabel, GImage, etc. for GUI and game design.  I never saw a "jar" file (I get the gist of what one is, but never saw one in the download), just a folder names "acm" and within it all these folders w/Java classes.

Comment: And the extension was of each file was .java? If it was that you download the source.. give me the link and i help you